# How to get datetime value from data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, bulkinsert

I have one csv file that contains one column with following data,

```
31/10/2014 10:27:12-05
31/10/2014 10:27:13.123-05
31/10/2014 10:27:14.123456-05
```

I need to move that data into Table named "`CsvData`" which contains one column `data1` which is `datetime` datatype.

Generally datetime format is should be like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql) `"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]"`, but my data is looks different.  I have over 100k rows like above 3 lines structure.

My Sample Output look should like below:

```
31/10/2014 10:27:12
31/10/2014 10:27:13
31/10/2014 10:27:14
```

I'm looking for good way to process entire file into SQL Server.

How to proceed?

Comment: what is `-05` in `10:27:12-05`?

Comment: Actually some data added with datetime this makes not able to insert into SQL Server. i don't know that what means '-05' and i am no need to store it?

Comment: Could -5 be the timezone?

Comment: no,should ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your file using format file where define this field as varchar(100) instead of datetime, after importing it as string take only 19 characters and cast them to datetime (selecting in a new table or adding a new datetime field)

Update:
you can ask bcp to generate format file, like this:

```
    create table dbo.dt_str(col1 varchar(100)); -- the table from which to generate fmt-file
    exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp b.dbo.dt_str format nul -c -t, -f z:\temp\dt_str.fmt -T'; --can be launched from cmd without xp_cmdshell
```

This generated the following file (3 rows):

> 10.0
>
> 1
>
> 1       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\r\n"   1     col1         Latin1_General_CI_AS

Then you load your file like this:

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.dt_str
    FROM 'z:\temp\dt.csv'
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'z:\temp\dt_str.fmt');
```

Control what is imported and if it can be converted to datetime:

```
    select col1, convert(datetime, left(col1, 19), 103)
    from dbo.dt_str;
```

Select into new_table:

```
    select convert(datetime, left(col1, 19), 103) as dt
    into dbo.dt_new
    from dbo.dt_str;
```

More on format files here: [Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: is this possible without using format file?i am interested to use bulk insert.

Comment: BULK INSERT supports format file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql. If it's possible or no depends on your field terminators, or how else can you instruct the server to see 31/10/2014 10:27:13.123-05 as a whole filed and not 2 fields

Comment: In past, i have tried bulk insert without using format file.How to write formatfile?

Comment: Thanks dude i look for this

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT of built in string function :

```
SELECT LEFT('31/10/2014 10:27:12-05',19)

OR 

SELECT LEFT(Your_columnname,19)
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help.

```
select convert(varchar(19),'31/10/2014 10:27:12',120) -- for datetime

select convert(varchar(10), '31/10/2014 10:27:12',120) -- for date only
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a staging table and insert your records from csv as it is.
Then try `SELECT LEFT('31/10/2014 10:27:14.123456-05',19)` to transform and load from staging table to main table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT` when importing.

```
DECLARE @Val NVARCHAR(100) = '31/10/2014 10:27:14.123456-05'
SELECT LEFT(@Val, CHARINDEX('-', @Val) - 1)
```